# Angular 8 application main.js bundle size issue

Tags: angular, bundle

I am facing issue after running 'ng build --prod' with main.js bundle size which was 2.4 MB earlier and it is 4.8 MB now. The reason behind this that pdfmake lib was getting bundled in '5-es5.4ea2bf12e34e479f38d4.js' file and after few changes in code pdfmake lib is getting bundled in 'main-es5.2f2f1bc83e70900695a8.js' file.

I used source-map-explorer to analyze the bundle size.

How does Angular create the bundles at the time of build and which files gets bundled in main.js.

Comment: my advice is to rollback to a previous commit and find out which change caused this problem and see if you can avoid it